# How to listen data changing in angular (with rx.js)

Tags: angular, typescript, stream, rxjs, observable

I am fetching data from back end

My service

```
  getItalianTeams() {
      return this.http.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opendatajson/football.json/master/2016-17/it.111.clubs.json")
      .map(result => result.json());
  }
```

My subscriber

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.teamService.getItalianTeams()
      .subscribe (
        (data) => {
          this.teams = data.clubs;
        }    
      )
  }

}
```

And for example some data was changed in back end.
How can I listen it in my component?

Comment: back-end to front-end communication is usually handled with websockets: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket. http requests are only a 1 time thing unless you're doing something like long-polling: https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-10-01-websockets-and-long-polling-in-javascript-ruby-and-python/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a websocket, or you can poll the api by calling it an an interval like below (will be updated every 5 seconds):

```
ngOnInit() {
    Observable
        .interval(5000) /* milliseconds between calls */
        .startWith(0) /* first call immediately */
        .switchMap(() => this.teamService.getItalianTeams())
        .subscribe((data) => {
            this.teams = data.clubs;
        })
  }
```

Comment: It make call to back end? I want to listen it like in websockets.